# Unable to pass IEnumerable<string> as parameter in Expression.Call

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

This is my class:

```
class SampleExpression
{
    public static void SampleEnum(IEnumerator<string> ien)
    {
        while (ien.MoveNext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ien.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how i am trying to invoke the `SampleEnum` method:

```
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ParameterExpression param2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SampleExpression), "args");

        var lstConstant = "1,2,3,4,".Split(new string[] { "," },
                                                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

        Expression ep = Expression.Constant(Expression.Constant(lstConstant, typeof(IEnumerable<string>)));
        var enummethod = typeof(SampleExpression).GetMethod("SampleEnum");
        MethodCallExpression methodCall = Expression.Call
                                        (
                                            enummethod
                                            , ep
                                        );

        var e = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerator<string>, string>>(methodCall, param2);
        e.Compile()(lstConstant.GetEnumerator());
    }
```

I get the following error in the line which tries to create the method call expression:

> Expression of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.TypedConstantExpression' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1[System.String]' of method 'Void Enum(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1[System.String])'

Please help.

Comment: public static void SampleEnum(***IEnumerator*** <string> ien) and typeof(***IEnumerable*** <string>) - Look carefully :)

Comment: Thanks Rob. You nailed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be very confused - it might help to have a look at how the C# compiler would generate a similar expression tree. In any case, there's a few mistakes you've made:

- `IEnumerable<T>` isn't `IEnumerator<T>`. They're not interchangeable.
- `param2` is a parameter expression that takes `SampleExpression`, while your lambda actually expects `IEnumerator<string>`.
- `ep` is a constant expression *of a constant expression*. That's not what you want. Remove the outer `Expression.Constant`.
- The lambda argument isn't actually used anyway - you can just use `Func<string>` instead of `Func<IEnumerator<string>, string>`.
- Your expression tree has no return value, while the lambda expects to return a `string`.

Assuming you want to have a lambda that takes `IEnumerator<string>` and uses it to call `SampleExpression.SampleEnum`, you could use something like this:

```
public void Test()
{
    var enumeratorParameter 
        = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerator<string>), "enumerator");

    var sampleEnumMethod = typeof(SampleExpression).GetMethod("SampleEnum");
    var methodCall = Expression.Call(sampleEnumMethod, enumeratorParameter);

    var e = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerator<string>, string>>
              (
                methodCall, 
                enumeratorParameter
              );

    var lstConstant = "1,2,3,4,".Split(',');
    e.Compile()(lstConstant.ToList().GetEnumerator());
}

class SampleExpression
{
    public static string SampleEnum(IEnumerator<string> ien)
    {
        while (ien.MoveNext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ien.Current);
        }

        return "Done!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Argh!! So many typos in my question. Thanks it got fixed :) - The main problem was the Ienumerator vs Ienumerable. And as you rightly stated the last point i needed an Action instead of a Func.

Comment: Luaan: would highly appreciate your help on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729400/how-do-i-convert-this-funcsampleexpression-ienumeratorstring-bool-to-funcs)