# How do i convert this Func<SampleExpression,IEnumerator<string>,bool>> to Func<SampleExpression,bool>>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

This is my class

```
class SampleExpression
{
    public string str;

    public static bool SampleEnum(SampleExpression s, IEnumerator<string> ien = null)
    {
        while (ien.MoveNext())
        {
            if (s.str == ien.Current)
            {
                ien.Reset();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is how i am generating my expression tree at runtime:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ParameterExpression param1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SampleExpression), "token");
        ParameterExpression param2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerator<string>), "args");

        var lstConstant = "1,2,3,4,".Split(new string[] { "," },
                           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

        var enummethod = typeof(SampleExpression).GetMethod("SampleEnum");
        MethodCallExpression methodCall = Expression.Call
                                        (
                                            enummethod,
                                            param1
                                            , param2
                                        );

        var e = Expression.Lambda<Func<SampleExpression, IEnumerator<string>, bool>>(methodCall, param1, param2);
        var l = e.Compile();

        List<SampleExpression> lst = new List<SampleExpression>();
        lst.Add(new SampleExpression { str = "1" }); // matches with lstConstant
        lst.Add(new SampleExpression { str = "2" }); // matches with lstConstant
        lst.Add(new SampleExpression { str = "5" });
        var items = lst.Where(x => l(x, lstConstant.GetEnumerator())).ToList();
    }
```

Now i might i have done this in a convoluted way(cause i am novice in Expression trees) - my requirement is this:

I have a comma separated string like this `"1,2,3,4,"`. I want to split and match each `SampleExpression` with the string parameter `str` of the class `SampleExpression`. Which i have done so far.

However i want the Expression as `Func<SampleExpression,bool>`. As you can see currently its `Func<SampleExpression, IEnumerator<string>, bool>`.

How do i fix this.

Comment: This seems like an enormously complicated way of doing something simple. Can you explain why you need an `Expression<>` for this? What is the intended use for this `Expression`? If you had a `Func<SampleExpression,bool>`, what items would you expect it to match? Also, why are you using an `IEnumerator` instead of `IEnumerable`? It seems like you could probably solve your use case a lot more simply if you focus on that instead of the way you think you need to solve it.

Comment: I have already admitted i am no expert and i know this is convoluted for sure.

Comment: Ignore how you are trying to get this done... tell us "what" you are trying to do.

Comment: Based on what you're saying, I'm thinking you can avoid using `Expression<>`s entirely, and just focus on `Func<>`s.

Comment: Do you have more operations other than IN?  Or will it always be `{PropertyName} IN {Set of Values}`?

Comment: So it will always be `{property} {operation} {set}` and you have the parser done.  So you are just trying to use Expression trees instead of reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression compilation seems weird to me too, but to actually answer your question...

You can wrap the compiled Func like so:

```
Func<SampleExpression, bool> lBind = (SampleExpression token) => l(token, lstConstant.GetEnumerator());
```

This binds the enumerator as the second parameter, while leaving the first open for your input.

Comment: Ah! This is it. I knew this had to something as simple as this, thanks :)

Comment: @ExpertNovice: By the way, you were already doing this in your question: the lambda you're providing to your `.Where()` method is equivalent to `lBind` in this answer, and it's being passed into `Where()` as a `Func<SampleExpression, bool>`. Did you just want a way to store this lambda for future use?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: My question heading clearly mentions the kind of Lambda i was looking for. I knew this had to be something very simple. And this answer did help me reduce quite a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me why you're doing dynamic expression compilation, so I'm just going to focus on your problem statement:

> I have a comma separated string like this `"1,2,3,4,"`. I want to split and match each `SampleExpression` with the string parameter `str` of the class `SampleExpression`.

LINQ actually provides a pretty easy way to handle this:

```
    var lstConstant = "1,2,3,4,".Split(new string[] { "," },
                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

    List<SampleExpression> lst = new List<SampleExpression>();
    lst.Add(new SampleExpression { str = "1" }); // matches with lstConstant
    lst.Add(new SampleExpression { str = "2" }); // matches with lstConstant
    lst.Add(new SampleExpression { str = "5" });

    var items = lst.Where(x => lstConstant.Contains(x.str)).ToList();
```

If you want to have this logic reside in the `SampleExpression` class, that's fine:

```
class SampleExpression
{
    public string str;

    public static bool SampleEnum(SampleExpression s, IEnumerable<string> ien)
    {
        return ien.Contains(s.str);
    }
}

// Usage:
var items = lst.Where(x => SampleExpression.SampleEnum(x, lstConstant))
    .ToList();
```

If you want the `SampleEnum` method itself to return the value to pass into the `Where` clause, you can do this instead:

```
class SampleExpression
{
    public string str;

    public static Func<SampleExpression, bool> SampleEnum(IEnumerable<string> ien)
    {
        return s => ien.Contains(s.str);
    }
}

// Usage:
var items = lst.Where(SampleExpression.SampleEnum(lstConstant))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Down-voters: An explanation for your down-vote is always appreciated.

Comment: Does not answer my query at all, I clearly need a lambda for future use which needs to be stored in memory compiled at runtime. This is in no way helping me.

Comment: @ExpertNovice: Thank you for your feedback. My final example includes a method that, when called, returns the delegate that you're saying you need. I assume you know how to store that result in a variable. Can you explain in what way that does not meet your needs?